# Elasticsearch authentication: Get error IOException[keystore password was incorrect] when set xpack enable to true

Tags: elasticsearch, security, certificate, kubernetes-helm, elk

been working on this helm chart lately and a couple of changes have persistently been showing issues. Attached here are the logs of the pod when it fails to run.

I have currently tried replicating this user's steps to fix pretty much the same issue:

https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/948

Along with that, these were two commands I used to create the secrets in order to troubleshoot:

```
kubectl create secret generic keystore-secure-password --from-literal=xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password='admin' -n monitoring

kubectl create secret generic trustore-secure-password --from-literal=xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password='admin' -n monitoring

kubectl create secret generic elastic-certificates --from-file=elastic-certificate.p12 -n monitoring
```

The stack trace:

```
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchSecurityException[failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to initialize SSL TrustManager]; nested: IOException[keystore password was incorrect]; nested: UnrecoverableKeyException[failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.];",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSSLConfigurations$5(SSLService.java:548) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:544) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:145) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:525) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:338) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$18(Node.java:733) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:747) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"... 6 more",
"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to initialize SSL TrustManager",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.StoreTrustConfig.createTrustManager(StoreTrustConfig.java:75) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.createSslContext(SSLService.java:453) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSSLConfigurations$5(SSLService.java:546) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:544) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:145) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:525) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:338) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$18(Node.java:733) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:747) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"... 6 more",
"Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect",
"at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2159) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221) ~[?:?]",
"at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.TrustConfig.getStore(TrustConfig.java:99) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.StoreTrustConfig.createTrustManager(StoreTrustConfig.java:66) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.createSslContext(SSLService.java:453) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSSLConfigurations$5(SSLService.java:546) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:544) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:145) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:525) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:338) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$18(Node.java:733) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:747) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"... 6 more",
"Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.",
"at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2159) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221) ~[?:?]",
"at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.TrustConfig.getStore(TrustConfig.java:99) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.StoreTrustConfig.createTrustManager(StoreTrustConfig.java:66) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.createSslContext(SSLService.java:453) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSSLConfigurations$5(SSLService.java:546) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:544) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:145) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:525) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:338) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$18(Node.java:733) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:747) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]",
"... 6 more"] }
uncaught exception in thread [main]
ElasticsearchSecurityException[failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to initialize SSL TrustManager]; nested: IOException[keystore password was incorrect]; nested: UnrecoverableKeyException[failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.];
Likely root cause: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2159)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.TrustConfig.getStore(TrustConfig.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.StoreTrustConfig.createTrustManager(StoreTrustConfig.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.createSslContext(SSLService.java:453)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSSLConfigurations$5(SSLService.java:546)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:544)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:525)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:338)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$18(Node.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:747)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77)
    <<<truncated>>>
For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/cmap-wlan-elasticsearch.log
```

My helm charts for the following look like this:

```
---
enabled: true
clusterName: "cmap-wlan-elasticsearch"
nodeGroup: "master"

# The service that non master groups will try to connect to when joining the cluster
# This should be set to clusterName + "-" + nodeGroup for your master group
masterService: ""

# Elasticsearch roles that will be applied to this nodeGroup
# These will be set as environment variables. E.g. node.master=true
roles:
  master: "true"
  ingest: "false"
  data: "true"
  remote_cluster_client: "false"
  ml: "false"

replicas: 3
minimumMasterNodes: 2

esMajorVersion: ""

# Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
# such as elasticsearch.yml and log4j2.properties
esConfig: 
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    indices.memory.index_buffer_size: "15%"
    xpack.security.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.supported_protocols: "TLSv1.2"
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificate.p12
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificate.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificate.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificate.p12
    transport.compress: true
    http.compression: true
    http.compression_level: 6

# Extra environment variables to append to this nodeGroup
# This will be appended to the current 'env:' key. You can use any of the kubernetes env
# syntax here
#extraEnvs:
#  - name: MY_ENVIRONMENT_VAR
#    value: the_value_goes_here

extraEnvs: 
  
#  - name: "ELASTIC_USERNAME"
#    value: "admin" 
#  - name: "ELASTIC_PASSWORD"
#    value: "admin" 
  - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: "elastic-credentials"
        key: "password"
  - name: ELASTIC_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: "elastic-credentials"
        key: "username"






# Allows you to load environment variables from kubernetes secret or config map
envFrom: []
# - secretRef:
#     name: env-secret
# - configMapRef:
#     name: config-map

# A list of secrets and their paths to mount inside the pod
# This is useful for mounting certificates for security and for mounting
# the X-Pack license
secretMounts:
   - name: elastic-certificates
     secretName: elastic-certificates
     path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
     defaultMode: 0755

hostAliases: []
#- ip: "127.0.0.1"
#  hostnames:
#  - "foo.local"
#  - "bar.local"

image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
imageTag: "7.16.1"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

podAnnotations: {}
  # iam.amazonaws.com/role: es-cluster

# additionals labels
labels: {}

esJavaOpts: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"

resources:
  requests: {}
  #  cpu: "1000m"
  #  memory: "2Gi"
  limits: {}
  #  cpu: "1000m"
  #  memory: "2Gi"

initResources: {}
  # limits:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   # memory: "128Mi"
  # requests:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   memory: "128Mi"

sidecarResources: {}
  # limits:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   # memory: "128Mi"
  # requests:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   memory: "128Mi"

networkHost: "0.0.0.0"

volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi

rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountAnnotations: {}
  serviceAccountName: ""

podSecurityPolicy:
  create: false
  name: ""
  spec:
    privileged: true
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
      - secret
      - configMap
      - persistentVolumeClaim
      - emptyDir

persistence:
  enabled: true
  labels:
    # Add default labels for the volumeClaimTemplate of the StatefulSet
    enabled: false
  annotations: {}

extraVolumes:
   - name: schemas
     configMap:
       name: elasticsearch-schemas-configmap 

extraVolumeMounts:
   - name: schemas
     mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/schemas
     readOnly: true
       
extraContainers: []
  # - name: do-something
  #   image: busybox
  #   command: ['do', 'something']

extraInitContainers: []
  # - name: do-something
  #   image: busybox
  #   command: ['do', 'something']

# This is the PriorityClass settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass
priorityClassName: ""

# By default this will make sure two pods don't end up on the same node
# Changing this to a region would allow you to spread pods across regions
antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"

# Hard means that by default pods will only be scheduled if there are enough nodes for them
# and that they will never end up on the same node. Setting this to soft will do this "best effort"
antiAffinity: "hard"

# This is the node affinity settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature
nodeAffinity: {}

# The default is to deploy all pods serially. By setting this to parallel all pods are started at
# the same time when bootstrapping the cluster
podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"

# The environment variables injected by service links are not used, but can lead to slow Elasticsearch boot times when
# there are many services in the current namespace.
# If you experience slow pod startups you probably want to set this to `false`.
enableServiceLinks: true

protocol: http
httpPort: 9200
transportPort: 9300

service:
  labels: {}
  labelsHeadless: {}
  type: NodePort
  nodePort: "30999"
  transportNodePort: "30175"  
  annotations: {}
  httpPortName: http
  transportPortName: transport
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  externalTrafficPolicy: ""

updateStrategy: RollingUpdate

# This is the max unavailable setting for the pod disruption budget
# The default value of 1 will make sure that kubernetes won't allow more than 1
# of your pods to be unavailable during maintenance
maxUnavailable: 1

podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: 1000
  runAsUser: 1000

securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
    - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000

# How long to wait for elasticsearch to stop gracefully
terminationGracePeriod: 120

sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 5

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/cluster-health.html#request-params wait_for_status
clusterHealthCheckParams: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s"

## Use an alternate scheduler.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
##
schedulerName: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []

# Enabling this will publically expose your Elasticsearch instance.
# Only enable this if you have security enabled on your cluster
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

# https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/63
masterTerminationFix: false

lifecycle:
   postStart:
     exec:
       command:
         - bash
         - -c
         - |
           #!/bin/bash
           ES_URL=http://localhost:9200
 
sysctlInitContainer:
  enabled: true

keystore:
  - secretName: keystore-secure-password
  - secretName: trustore-secure-password

networkPolicy:
  ## Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources. Only Ingress traffic is filtered for now.
  ## In order for a Pod to access Elasticsearch, it needs to have the following label:
  ## {{ template "uname" . }}-client: "true"
  ## Example for default configuration to access HTTP port:
  ## elasticsearch-master-http-client: "true"
  ## Example for default configuration to access transport port:
  ## elasticsearch-master-transport-client: "true"

  http:
    enabled: false
    ## if explicitNamespacesSelector is not set or set to {}, only client Pods being in the networkPolicy's namespace
    ## and matching all criteria can reach the DB.
    ## But sometimes, we want the Pods to be accessible to clients from other namespaces, in this case, we can use this
    ## parameter to select these namespaces
    ##
    # explicitNamespacesSelector:
    #   # Accept from namespaces with all those different rules (only from whitelisted Pods)
    #   matchLabels:
    #     role: frontend
    #   matchExpressions:
    #     - {key: role, operator: In, values: [frontend]}

    ## Additional NetworkPolicy Ingress "from" rules to set. Note that all rules are OR-ed.
    ##
    # additionalRules:
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchLabels:
    #         role: frontend
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchExpressions:
    #         - key: role
    #           operator: In
    #           values:
    #             - frontend

  transport:
    ## Note that all Elasticsearch Pods can talks to themselves using transport port even if enabled.
    enabled: false
    # explicitNamespacesSelector:
    #   matchLabels:
    #     role: frontend
    #   matchExpressions:
    #     - {key: role, operator: In, values: [frontend]}
    # additionalRules:
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchLabels:
    #         role: frontend
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchExpressions:
    #         - key: role
    #           operator: In
    #           values:
    #             - frontend

# Deprecated
# please use the above podSecurityContext.fsGroup instead
fsGroup: ""
```